# Как сделать авторизацию только в одной сессии?

Tags: javascript, firebase, extension

Есть расширение хром с авторизацией firebase. Я создал пользователя с email/паролем и на данный момент можно авторизоваться по этому имейл с разных устройств. Как разрешить вход только на одном устройстве?

Comment: Как вариант: при авторизации сгенерировать ключ, который пишется в сессию/куки (не знаю куда правильнее), и сверять с тем, что есть в базе.